# How do messengers, using WebSocket send messages to a defenite chat or group?

Tags: node.js, websocket

I have a node JS server, with WebSocket server on it.
Everything works fine, i'm trying to make groups and chats.
So, how does server send messeges to only **one group**?

My WS server:

```
const server = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 3000 })
server.on('connection', ws => {
    ws.on('message', message => {
        if (message === 'exit') {
            ws.close()
        } else {
            server.clients.forEach(client => {
                if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
                    client.send(message)
                }
            })
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: If multiple users are connected to the server, there will be multiple web socket connections, each with a different client. The server must keep track of these and know which one to select when sending a message. `server.clients.forEach` sounds as if they are all treated the same, which should not be the case.